# Is it possible to combine and control multiple USB cams with a RPI

Tags: raspberry-pi, hardware, webcam, lan, switching

I'm a developer for different mobile and backend systems and pretty new to network and hardware stuff. I want to build a system/network with 6 cameras placed 100m away in the field, which I want to control with a web interface. I know how to build such interfaces, but I have no clue how to connect the hardware. I thought about the following:

I need 6 cameras(*infos added below) standing side by side with ca. 1.5m space between. These should be connected to a switch, so a 100m wire (USB or LAN, I prefer LAN) goes to a RPI which can setup the web interface controlling the cameras like ".../whatever/camera-slot-ip-or-number".

As I said in the introduction, I have no clue how to start, because actually webcams using USB as a std, but does they provide wake on LAN features? Or is it better to do it with 6 USB-cams and several RPIs?

I hope someone with a better hardware understanding can help me.

Thanks a lot

Specification for the cameras:
HD is not needed, but it should recognize a 0,5cm round hole in a 50x50cm area properly. The distance between camera and object is 7-10m A color image should transmitted, but there only 2 main-colors.

EDIT:
draft 2.0:
[image: draft cam with rpi solution 2.0]

Comment: Is there significant processing to be done on the images? Or not? What image size are you using (width x height) in pixels? Colour or greyscale? What frame rate do you need? All these things will have a significant impact on the bandwidth required.

Comment: No, there isn't. It's just a model to show the planned architecture of the system including the cams and different rpis. It's a good argument to look for the frame rate, but at least I never worked with cameras before. I don't need HD, but it should recognize a 0,5cm round hole in a 50x50cm area properly, coloring is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Piping USB through a 100m cable is not easily going to work.
Some models of USB cameras can be used with the Raspberry pi, but the performance (speed of taking a picture, and image quality too) are better with the 'native' raspberry pi camera.

The Pi also has a built-in H.264 video encoder, so you can stream live video with relative ease if you want to. A quick and brute way of doing that is to pipe the output from the built-in raspivid application to your own application that then handles flow control and pipes the data further to a socket.

If wifi does nto work for you, then you could pick some other raspberry pi model with an ethernet interface and go that way.

Also, the cost of additional Raspberry Pis (especially the zero w) is so low that the easiest and most cost efficient thing might just be to one raspberry pi camera on 6 raspberry pi's. If connecting them with Wifi works in your application, you can use the Zero W model and then you just need to feed power to them via cable.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know that 100m of USB is not the very best idea. I don't get your idea to use 6 rpi cameras instead of 6 'normal' cameras. Or do you think to connect each usb-camera to one rpi and these rips to one master rpi and connect this one to the front rpi providing the web interface?

Comment: Please have a look at my draft picture I added to the question.

Comment: Your best bet is to use the rasbberry pi camera : https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/camera-module-v2/, as opposed to any USB connected regular webacm. I don't at the moment get what you mean by the "normal" camera. Re: your drawing, if you have a rpi for each raspberry pi camera, you probably don't need what you have as "rpi backend master", an ethernet switch (or wifi access point) will do.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the updated information. I am pretty much in agreement, I think, with Sami's answer but wanted to add a few more details that are a bit big and unwieldy for a comment.

If you look across the top of your diagram, you have 6 stations at 1.5m intervals, so the width of your diagram is 7.5m. That is easily within wifi range so I am thinking a wifi access point on any of the 6 stations and a 100m Cat 6 Ethernet cable down the length of your diagram to the front-end.

As your processing doesn't sound too involved, you can likely get away with just a Raspberry Pi Zero W and a v2 camera at each station and save a fair bit of money vis-à-vis Raspberry Pi 3B+.

One thing that does concern me is looking for 0.5cm from 7-10m. The lens on the Raspberry Pi camera is pretty wide angle and a 0.5cm hole is going to be awfully small at 10m in a wide angle shot unless at very high resolution. I haven't done the maths, but I think you will be looking for a telephoto lens if such a thing exists... the maths now follows.

The [horizontal field of view](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/camera/) (FOV) of v2 camera is 62 degrees, so half that is 31 degrees and the camera is 1000cm away. So:

```
tan(31 degrees) = half the FOV width / 1000
```

So, at 10m you will get 1200cm of stuff across your image and that will be imaged by 3,280 pixels on the sensor if you shoot at the very highest resolution. So, **each pixel** in your image will correspond to an area 0.3cm wide whereas you are looking for holes 0.5cm wide - so it will be pretty marginal as to whether you can make it out... maths is subject to revision after a glass of wine later.